# Problem with making the nav bar clear with no colors in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

The problem is that i want to make the Nav-bar clear with no color and i just can't, i made it clear in anther projects but in this one it seems not be working for me . what is the problem ???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBrEr.jpg

I tried making it transparent with the usual functions of nav bar mentioned below but it is not working.

```
extension UINavigationBar {
 func transparentNavigationBar() {
    self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.isTranslucent = true
 }
}
```

//

```
class ProductVC: UIViewController {

var loadingView = LoadingView()
let mainView = ProductV()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(mainView)


    mainView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.bottom.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
    //        view.addSubview(loadingView)
    //        loadingView.isHidden = false
    //        loadingView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    //            make.center.width.height.equalToSuperview()
    //        }
    //        dataload()
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.transparentNavigationBar()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();

    mainView.dsv.frame = mainView.detailView.bounds; // Instead of using auto layout
    mainView.dsv.contentSize.height = 3000; // Or whatever you want it to be.
}


/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
}extension UINavigationBar {
func transparentNavigationBar() {
    self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
     self.isTranslucent = true
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling transparentNavigationBar()?

Comment: I tried calling it in didLoad, willApper and nothing seem to work. I am making the nav bar transparent in some views, like it is not 100% clear but shows a blur but in this view i want to totally hide it except for the bar buttons.

Comment: See in the interface debugger if there is any other view present at that position.

Comment: The problem not if there is a view, the nav bar is being blur.

Comment: Add the screenshot.

Comment: @PGDev I add one .

Comment: Add the code where you're calling transparentNavigationBar().

Comment: This is the whole code for the VC.

Comment: The problem is with the mainView that you're adding as the subView. Without it, the code works just fine.

Comment: Still not working for me even after i removed the mainView. Maybe the previous VC is effecting it??

Comment: How are you pushing ProductVC? Add the code.

Comment: I am using delegate :
    func setNav(vc: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc.self, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    let img = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor =   UIColor.clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor =  UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, I tried it and it works well, you can check these two things

Is the iboulet well created?

```
@IBOutlet weak var NavigationBar: UINavigationBar!
```

Make sure you have this line in your viewcontroller.

```
navigationBar.transparentNavigationBar ()
```

Comment: I am not using storyboard i am using code so outlet not working for me .

Answer (score 0):

The `extension` method that you've added is working fine for me after calling it in `viewWillAppear(_:)`, i.e.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transparentNavigationBar()
    }
}
```

Kindly elaborate the scenario if it still don't work.